# Wysiwyg style web based editor for Microsoft RDLC report

Tags: asp.net, web, rdlc

I have been searching for wysiwyg style web based editor for Microsoft RDLC report. But had no luck so far. I'm were of fyireporting, but it doesn't seem to fit the bill. The idea is to allow customer to edit their report layout and use preset report parameters to provide database data for the report. Any idea how this can be accomplished?

Sry, for my bad english. Any help is appreciated!